# Italian consulate in Dubai annulled my visa after my family applied

Tags: schengen, pakistani-citizens, rome, visa-cancellation

My case is very simple and straightforward. I applied for my Schengen Visa and got it on 10 October 18, for traveling to Italy on 13 December 2018 without Interview. My family showed interest later to join me. Therefore, I put forward their applications as well, by attaching my issued visa copy.

Very next day I got an email and call to come to Consulate for interview with my family to sign the Children authorization letter in front of Visa Officer. When we reached the Consulate, they started asking question about my visa instead of my family visa application. They try to prove that I got the visa with false intention, planning to not leave the Schengen territory after my visit and told me you are not going to Italy. They later put an annulled stamp on the visa page of my passport.

Visa officer believed that you got visa yourself and now you are asking visa for your family so you are planning to run away. Even though I have a 15 year old executive job with Gratuity, 2 school kids, and own house in Dubai.

I am not interested in leaving my current executive job and migrate illegally  to do odd jobs in Europe in the age of 40.

Furthermore, when I tried to withdraw my family application from Consulate, they refused to withdraw as well.

So consider these facts before applying the visa in Italian Consulate in Dubai.

Comment: What was the stated purpose of your trip?

Comment: Tourism only, to visit the Rome.

Comment: Get an attorney. Advice for appeals should not be solicited from online forums.

Comment: The consulate deceived you but they cannot be held accountable for lying. On the contrary, they accused YOU of lying. You can try appealing, but you would need an Italian lawyer and it could get costly. This annulment will have a detrimental effect on your future visa applications.

Comment: @greatone, have you considered the possibility that something was lost in translation? While it is impolite to criticize the language skills of a second language speaker, the posting here makes me wonder if both sides understood each other.

Comment: @Alladitta Do you have any travel history that shows you have previously complied with visas granted to you? What is your nationality?

Comment: Nationality Pakistan.
Travel History: South Korea, Saudi Arabia,
A previous Schengen Visa on 21-08-18 received but I did not travel due to family issues.

Comment: @HonoraryWorldCitizen The question is entirely reasonable, namely “is it worth considering at all?” For a mere refusal, I would say no. For an annulment, I would say yes and you need an attorney (as you pointed out). That's the answer.

Comment: @Alladitta It is possible that the Embassy granted the first visa because your family ties were seen as being a compelling reason for you to return, and that if you’d applied as a family from the outset the application would have been refused.

Comment: It should be noted that *revoked* and *cancelled* are distinct.  *Annulled* corresponds to *cancelled.*

Comment: Have you considered simply withdrawing the visa application for your family?

Comment: It seems rather unlikely that you would go for tourism in Italy by yourself, while your family stays behind...

Comment: Thanks for the edit but now there isn't even a question, so I'm voting to leave closed.

Answer (score 9):

You should definitely consider an appeal, not to salvage this trip (there is not enough time) but to avoid having an annulment on your record (in Schengen terminology, an annulment implies fraud and is definitely worse than a revocation or a mere refusal).

It is however very difficult to lodge a successful appeal and not something you can hope to do yourself. You will need to instruct an Italian attorney for that, in particular one with a practice in immigration law if you can locate one from where you currently are.

Comment: One more thing, Application for my Family visa [Wife + Kids] are still awaiting for outcome in the Consulate General of Italy. I don't know why they have not decided  till date even after all this issue.

Comment: @Alladitta They clearly believe you're all intending illegal immigrants, and are doing the appropriate research

Comment: @coke what research? The same information they used in canceling the husbands visa will be appilicable.

Comment: @HonoraryWorldCitizen They may perform additional checks of each family member, which will be easier with their passports in hand

Comment: Thanks to all,
Should I withdraw my family visa application to avoid refusal ?
Any suggestion about best attorney to help me in this situation, possibly available in Dubai.

Comment: @greatone. Yes I visited the Consulate to withdraw application for my family, they refused to withdraw and told me to hand over the results in next 24 hours.